# Creating an array and then get min using while loop

Tags: java, arrays, min

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] numbers = new int[10];

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter number");
    numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
}

for (int i = 10 ; i > numbers.length ; i++)
{
    int min = numbers [i];
    if ( numbers [i] > min)
    numbers [i] = input.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("the min values is " + min  );
```

i stopped here ..please help
i want to count the minimum value from the input from the user

Comment: Why do you want to create an array for the min? By definition there is only one minimum value.

Comment: Do you have to use an array? You could just take the min of the input values.

Comment: Your loops are inconsistent, and probably that is part of your confusion. The 2nd loop is never entered.

Comment: ...and fix your compiler errors before posting, please.

Comment: i have to use the array and for while :)

Comment: What do you mean by "for while"? These are different things (that can do the same) - `for` loop and `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

To take the minimum of 10 inputs you can do

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int min = InStream.range(0, 10)
                  .peek(i -> System.out.println("Please enter number"))
                  .map(i -> input.nextInt())
                  .min();
System.out.println("the min values is " + min);
```

> what is wrong in your code

```
for (int i = 10 ; i > numbers.length ; i++)
```

This won't work because the last index is `[9]` not `[10]` also you are incrementing instead of decrementing, you need something like

```
for (int i = numbers.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
```

You would be able to see this in a debugger, or by reading the error message such as `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException: 10`

Comment: Yes it works and does the job, but if the OP has problems with simple for loops, I don't think that your answer means anything to him.

Comment: @TDG I suspect using a debugger or reading error messages is some else which doesn't meaning anything either.

Comment: im here for learning ..

Comment: @mo7al876any my hint would be, when you get an error message, read it. If you don't know what it means, google it or at least post it in the question.

Comment: @mo7al876any I have added what would be the simplest fix to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to understand a lot of thing with you code is wrong.

Approach 1:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] numbers = new int[10];

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter number");
    numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
}
int min = numbers [0]; // Need to initialize it here outside the loop
for (int i = 1 ; i < numbers.length ; i++) // Need to count from 2nd element to the last
{
    if ( numbers [i] < min) // changing condition if number is less than min
         min = numbers [i]; // setting min to that number
}
System.out.println("the min values is " + min  );
```

Approach 2: 
Here we check for the minimum value when the use is entering the value itself.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] numbers = new int[10];
boolean flagForMin = true;
int min;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter number");
    numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
    if(flagForMin) {
        min=numbers[i];
        flagForMin=false;
    } else {
         if ( numbers [i] < min) 
            min = numbers [i];
    }
}
System.out.println("the min values is " + min  );
```

These are with the for loop approach you can change the loop to while by initialing before the loop & incrementing the counter in last statement of the loop.

EG:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] numbers = new int[10];
boolean flagForMin = true;
int min;
int i = 0;
while( i < numbers.length)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter number");
    numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
    if(flagForMin) {
        min=numbers[i];
        flagForMin=false;
    } else {
         if ( numbers [i] < min) 
            min = numbers [i];
    }
    i++;
}
System.out.println("the min values is " + min  );
```

Comment: thannkkkks man you save me

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use 2 `for` loops. You do not even need an array. Take a look:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter number");
            int number = input.nextInt();

            if (number < min) {
                min = number;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("the min values is " + min);
    }
}
```